# ¿Cómo cambiar la fuente por defecto en una aplicación Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un ejemplo de cómo cambiar el tipo de fuente a un texto, pero lo que necesito es aplicarlo de forma global para no estar poniéndoselo a cada `TextView`:

```
public class ActividadEjemplo extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ejemplo);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    String font_path = "font/Quicksand-Regular.ttf";
    Typeface fuente = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),font_path);
    text.setTypeface(fuente);
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para usar [**Calligraphy**](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) de manera rápida, creas tu proyecto y agregas la referencia a la libreria

```
dependencies {
   compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
}
```

Luego creas una clase que haga un ***extends*** a la clase ***Application***

**MiAplicacion.java**

```
public class MiAplicacion extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                    .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf")
                    .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                    .build()
      );
  }
}
```

Luego en tu archivo **AndroidManifest.xml**, dentro del tag ***application*** en la propiedad ***android:name*** colocas el nombre de tu clase creada anteriormente, quedando así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.brandot">

  <application
    android:name=".MiAplicacion"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/title_name"        
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Luego dentro de tu proyecto en el directorio **assets** colocas tus tipos de letras, en mi caso tengo **assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf**. Y luego en tu clase **Main** agregas lo siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
  }    

  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
  }
}
```

De esta forma haces que todos tus componentes dentro de la actividad carguen al tipo de letra por defecto, que en este caso es **Roboto-Regular.ttf**.

Comment: Bien explicado, me sirvió de mucho me pregunto si esto afectara a los `fragment`

Comment: @Santiago, hasta donde he podido probar, si se ven afectados.

Answer (score 3):

Para hacerlo de forma global te recomiendo usar [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy). Puedes definir fuentes globales para toda la aplicación o incluso asignar dentro del XML fuentes que se encuentren en tus assets.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Primero debes agregarlo a tu archivo gradle como dependencia:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
}
```

Debes tener una clase que extienda de [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Application.html) al que debes agregar el siguiente código en su método `onCreate()`:

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf") //Fuente agregada en los assets dentro de la carpeta fonts
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());
```

Finalmente en cada `Activity` que quieras que tenga las fuentes por defecto, tienes que agregar el siguiente código:

```
 @Override
 protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));   
 }
```

Toda esta información está también disponible en el repositorio de Github de esta biblioteca.

Comment: La clase que extienda de Aplication la tengo que crear, y después instanciarla dentro de las demás Actividades porque todas mis clases extienden de AppCompatActivity o Fragment.

Comment: Creas la clase que extiende de Application y luego registras esta clase en el manifest, en la etiqueta <Application android:name=".TuClase" .... />
Lo de las actividades es aparte. En el repo de la biblioteca debe haber un proyecto de ejemplo, deberías dale una mirada ;)